# How can I export an .xoj file to pdf so that the whole file is exported, not just my edits?

Tags: pdf, editing

I opened a pdf file in xournal and edited it using a stylus. After saving as a xournal file,with .xoj extension, I selected export as .pdf from the file menu.

When I went to open the new file in pdf viewer and in xournal, all that was visible were the editing marks I had made, and none of the original document.

I'm using ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of opening the .pdf file directly, I selected "annotate pdf" from the file menu. That opened a dialogue box that allowed me to choose the file to edit. Once done, exporting as .pdf resulted in the complete file - original and edit - to be viewed.

(Leaving this here in case anyone else runs across this problem.)

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to export as a pdf format.

Comment: This does not solve the problem in the post (that it only exports the additions and doesn't include the original document).